# How to make a timer reset back to 0 seconds every 10 seconds?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, timer

*I have these timers one is for updating the timer text and the other is for setting off a sound every ten seconds, both timers will just run until I stop them but I need them once they hit 10 seconds for the sound to go off then for the timer resets back to 0 seconds and count up back to ten seconds and so on*

import UIKit
import AVFoundation
class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
var running = false

@IBOutlet weak var timer: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    running = false
    }
var timer3 = Timer()
var time5 = 00.00
var player: AVAudioPlayer!
var timer4 = Timer()

@IBAction func resetBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    timer.text = "00.00"
    timer3.invalidate()
}


@IBAction func stopBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    timer3.invalidate()
    timer4.invalidate()
  running = false
}





@IBAction func startBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    if running == true {
       return
        
    } else {
    running = true
    timer3 = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateLabel), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
     timer4 = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10.0, target: self, selector: #selector(playSound), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
};

@objc func updateLabel() {
    time5 += 1
    timer.text = String(time5)
}

@objc func playSound() {
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "mixkit-system-beep-buzzer-fail-2964", withExtension: "wav")
    player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)
    player.play()
    
    
    
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset variable `time5`

```
@objc func playSound() {
   let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "mixkit-system-beep-buzzer-fail-2964", withExtension: "wav")
   player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)
   player.play()
   time5 = 0.0 // reset here 
}
```

You can also make it 1 timer which ticks every 1 second

```
@objc func updateLabel() {
   time5 += 1
   timer.text = String(time5) 
   if time5 >= 10.0 {
     let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "mixkit-system-beep-buzzer-fail-2964", withExtension: "wav")
     player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)
     player.play()
     time5 = 0.0 // reset here 
   }
}
```

Comment: The variable should be update in here is time5 = 0.0 not timer5 = 0.0. By the way I think you should add time5 = 0.0 in resetBtn too because when reset the variable should be reset too.